# Standard error codes for json schema validation

Tags: json, validation, rest, jsonschema

While implementing json schema validation in my REST api, I started wondering if there are any standard error codes for the validation errors.

I haven't been able to find any around, so I just wanted to know if I was missing something, or if none exist.

By error codes I mean something along the lines of `E0042 - Property is not a number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I haven't been able to find any around, so I just wanted to know if I was missing something, or if none exist.

None exist! The [specification](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html) does not detail any error codes or how the validation result are to be presented. That makes sense since JSON and JSON-Schema are technology agnostic, so a language might opt for error codes, another one for throwing exceptions, etc. And sometimes you might want to return these to your clients making them part of your API. Not restricting the validation result allows for flexibility in your API.